# Anychart tables: How to include thousand separators?

Tags: anychart

How can I put the text "100.000" in a table in Anychart? When I try to get the string "100.000" in, it is modified to "100".

For a working example see https://jsfiddle.net/Republiq/xcemvm9L/

```
table = anychart.standalones.table(2,2);
table.getCell(0,0).content("100.000");
table.container("container").draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use such number formatting for the whole table you can define numberLocale in the beginning. If the actual number is 100 and '.' - is a decimal separator and you want to show 3 zeros as decimals, put the following lines before creating the table:

```
anychart.format.locales.default.numberLocale.decimalsCount = 3;
anychart.format.locales.default.numberLocale.zeroFillDecimals = true;
```

And then put in the number as:

```
table.getCell(0,0).content(100);
```

If '.' - is a group separator and the actual number is 100000, put the following line:
    anychart.format.locales.default.numberLocale.groupsSeparator = '.';
And then put in the number as:

```
 table.getCell(0,0).content(100000);
```

If you want to use special format only for a single cell, we recommend you to use number formatter, which helps to configure all these options only for a single number. For example, it may looks like:

```
table = anychart.standalones.table(5,5);
table.getCell(0,0).content(anychart.format.number(100000, 3, ".", ","));
table.container("container").draw();
```

Also, you may learn more about this useful method and find examples [in this article](https://api.anychart.com/8.0.1/anychart.format#number)