# How to make comma as thousand separator in anychart

Tags: javascript, charts, anychart

I have 4 graphs on one page and one of them displays big values(in millions and thousands) I need to separate number with comma so it can be more readable but I didn't find any solution on the internet and all my attempts just end up in not displaying graph at all.
Here is chart.html file:

```
<div id="container"></div>

    <script>
        anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
            const dataStock = []
            const dataCCI = []
            const fedFund = []
            const smartMoney = []
            {%for y in smart_money%}           
            currentDate = new Date("{{y.dateY}}")
            formatDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
            smartMoney.push([formatDate,"{{y.value|floatformat:0}}"])    
            {%endfor%}
            {%for stock in stocks %}
            currentDate = new Date("{{stock.date}}")
            formatDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
            dataStock.push([formatDate, "{{stock.open}}", "{{stock.high}}",
                "{{stock.low}}", "{{stock.price}}"])
            yVal = "{{stock.low}}" - 10
            if ("{{stock.strategy.color}}") {
                if ("{{stock.strategy.color}}" == 'light green') {
                    color = 'Chartreuse'
                    color_name = 'light green'
                } else if ("{{stock.strategy.color}}" == 'purple') {
                    color = 'MediumSlateBlue'
                    color_name = 'purple'
                } else if ("{{stock.strategy.color}}" == 'light purple') {
                    color = 'DarkOrchid'
                    color_name = 'light purple'
                }
                else {
                    color_name = "{{stock.strategy.color}}"
                    color = "{{stock.strategy.color}}"
                }


                dataCCI.push([
                    formatDate, yVal, { fill: color, markerSize: 2 }, color_name
                ],)
            }


            {% endfor %}

            {%for i in interest %}
            currentDate = new Date("{{i.interest_date}}")
            formatDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
            fedFund.push([formatDate, "{{i.strategy_interest}}"])
            {% endfor %}
            
            // Strategy
            table = anychart.data.table(0)
            table.addData(dataCCI)
            mapping = table.mapAs({ value: 1, 'marker': 2 });

            // Fed fund
            table2 = anychart.data.table();
            table2.addData(fedFund)
            mapping2 = table.mapAs()

            // Smart money Y
            table3 = anychart.data.table();
            table3.addData(smartMoney)
            mapping3 = table.mapAs()

            let chart = anychart.stock(true);
            var candlePlot = chart.plot(0)
            var markerPlot = chart.plot(1)
            var fedPlot = chart.plot(2)
            var smartMoneyPlot = chart.plot(3)

            chart.background().fill({
                src: "{% static 'images/bg_chart.jpg'%}",
                mode: "fit-max",
                opacity: 0.4
            });

            candlePlot.candlestick(dataStock).name('{{ticker}}');
            markerPlot.marker(mapping).name('Dark Pool');
            fedPlot.column(fedFund).name('X')
            smartM = smartMoneyPlot.column(smartMoney).name('Y')
            var labels = smartM.labels();
    labels.format(function() {

        // Set format for number using object.
        return anychart.format.number(this.value, {scale: true, zeroFillDecimals: true, scaleSuffixSeparator: '$'})
    });
            chart.container("container");
            chart.draw();


            var rangeSelector = anychart.ui.rangeSelector();
            var rangePicker = anychart.ui.rangePicker();

            // specify which chart range selector controls

            rangeSelector.target(chart);
            rangePicker.target(chart);
            var title = chart.title('{{ticker}}');
            // render the chart
            chart.container("container");
            chart.draw();

            // Render the range selection controls into containers on a page
            rangeSelector.render(document.getElementById("rangeselectorContainer"));
            rangePicker.render(document.getElementById("rangepickerContainer"));
        });


    </script>
```

Chart under name smart money is chart where I need this thousand separator. This is how one data is displayed now 8733787 and it should be like this 8,733,787. I removed all my attempts at making this feature on the chart so it doesn't confuse anyone. Also note that this for loops are django template loops that I use to get data to JS list from backend.
I managed to add separated numbers values to data lists but then graph just disappears. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673908/anychart-tables-how-to-include-thousand-separators

Comment: @James I saw that article but I couldn't figure out how to implement that in stock chart because they use table.getCell() function

Comment: OK - check http://6.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/number-formatting.html#thousands-separastor - It looks like you could add `thousandsSeparator: ','` to the settings object in the call to anychart.format.number

Comment: It's XML code I am using HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `format()` method to set a comma for separating thousands of an integer number.
Here is the documentation for the [anychart formatting method](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Text_Formatters#overview) and the [axes labels formatting](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Axes_Labels_Formatting#overview).
The sample for such use is provided below.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  var chart = anychart.column();

  // setting title
  chart.title("The comma as thousand separator");

  // setting data
  chart.column([
    ["People's Republic of China", 10000],
    ["India", 200000],
    ["United States of America", 3000]
  ]);

  // adjusting labels by utilizing format() method
  var yLabels = chart.yAxis().labels();
  yLabels.format("${%value}{groupsSeparator:\\,}");

  // force labels to hide value, if the previous one is too big, set text position to center
  var xAxis = chart.xAxis();
  xAxis.overlapMode(false);

  // draw chart
  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-base.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```